# Angular 4 routing doesn't work on prod

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm developing an angular 4 web app, and did routing like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: "raids", pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'raids',
        component: RaidsContainerComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'gyms',
        component: GymsContainerComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'raid/:rid',
        component: RaidDetailsComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'user',
        component: UsersContainerComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent
    }, 
    { path: '**', redirectTo: "raids", pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

when i'm on local host and I write in the url line localhost/raids it gets me to RaidsContainerComponent as it should, but when I do the same on production after I've published the app, I get:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is that your only routing, or do you have lazy loading or anything else ?

Comment: you should use router links in the application instead of entering URL in url bar,  https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links

Comment: @Erez have you add <base href=”/” /> in your index.html

Comment: You are using `PathLocationStrategy` in which the server needs to be able to return the main application code for every URL .The local development server started by the Angular CLI does support this functionality that's why it worked in dev mode but not in prod.

Comment: @trichetriche what's lazy loading? I'm kinda new to this, I have only this routing..

Vikas I also used the routerlink in my links to reference those pages but that's not my problem, I want it also to work on direct url entering.

SuvethanNantha I did <base href="/" />

Comment: @Vikas so how can make it in prod?

Answer (score 1):

OK I've figured it out, in order to publish my site to azure i had to make web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="angular cli routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but ng-build didn't add it to the dist file so i had to add it manually to the ftp server, now its working.